# How does one specify point size in a plotly express strip plot?

Tags: python, plotly

I would have thought it was easy, but I could not find the answer anywhere.

[The documentation on strip plots does not mention anything about marker size.](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.strip.html)

For more detail, I am trying to overlay a jittered strip plot on top of a boxplot. I could not do that in `go` so I resorted to mixing `go` and `px`:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.strip(df, 
               x="species", y="sepal_width", color="species", 
               title="This is a stripplot!", 
               stripmode = "overlay"   # Select between "group" or "overlay" mode
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(
        x = df.species,
        y = df.sepal_width
    )
)
```

However the points are too big in my specific case, and I wanted to make them smaller. Is the only way to go into the traces for the `px` object and manually change it from there???

For reference, this is what works right now:

```
for trace in fig.select_traces():
    trace.marker.update(size = 3)
```

but it seems overkill just to do something that should be easy to do directly from `strip`

Comment: seems reasonable to me.  same as `fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update({"marker":{"size":3}})`

Comment: ahhhhh there's a `for_each_trace`, I didn't know that, thanks!
I still think a `pointsize` argument would be better though, but this is easy enough.